# asp.net 4.0 - When I create a custom control that inherits from HtmlContainerControl, I can't get it to show up in the VS Toolbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I've tried two methods to include my custom control in the toolbox.

First, I tried to drag the DLL onto my toolbox, but only some of my controls appeared.

Again, when I did it the "choose items" way, only some of my controls appeared.

Any of my custom controls that inherit from Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl don't show up.

However, if I change those controls' classes to inherit from Web.UI.Panel instead, they do show up.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you decorate it with attributes for the [ToolBoxItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.toolboxitemattribute.aspx)?